# ExpanderView header style in expanded state

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I want to customize style of ExpanderView Header (from Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone).
For example I want to change Header's foreground to orange. How can I reach it?
Here's my ExpanderView style (I removed vertical line and tilt effect on Header, but can't do what I want):

```
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderViewStyle1" TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Collapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-35"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expandable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Expander" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.0" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check your own custom template by here

"http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=184"

Hope this helps